# Bug report on "quoting" and venue question.

Tags: bug, status-completed

First, bug report (hopefully so this post is transfered to the correct site.

When I paste:

Area of Effect: An area attack creates an area of effect, usually a burst or a wall, within range. An area attack affects certain targets within its area of effect, which has a certain size. An area attack’s area of effect, range, and targets are specified in its power description.

And quote it (either through keyboard ctrl-q or through the quote button on chrome I get:

---

its power description.

its power description.> Area of Effect: An area attack creates

> an area of effect, usually a burst or
>   a wall, within range. An area attack
>   affects certain targets within its
>   area of effect, which has a certain
>   size. An area attack’s area of effect,
>   range, and targets are specified in
>   its power description.its power description.

its power description.

---

is this the correct venue to report such a thing? If not, what is? the question isn't handled in the FAQ section.

Comment: What version of Chrome are you using? [Here's a list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported/56192#56192) of supported browsers and note that browsers in beta (like IE9) are **not** supported.

Comment: Chrome on XP, fully supported.

Comment: [This](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56610/150909) appears to report a similar problem... that one is attributed to a bug in `Chrome` 6.0.* as of 12 Sept 2010. (see comment after JeffAtwood's answer)

Comment: Ah, as I'm not using "stable" I'm SOL. That's... kind of annoying.

Comment: The joys of the cutting edge. For what it's worth, I just paste text in and then manually add a > to the front of the paragraph. Works a charm.

Comment: This appears to no longer occur so I've marked it status-completed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly this is a bug in Chrome.. they need to fix it on their end.